# How to add dynamic meta tags to react app based on Django API

Tags: django, reactjs, amazon-s3, meta-tags, server-side-rendering

I have a React front-end and a Django (DRF) API. The React front-end has a route like /content/:id where a different page with a different image is rendered depending on the `:id`. I'd like to change the index.html meta tags based off the content from that request which comes from Django.

There are many tutorials on how to do this with express and React: http://www.kapwing.com/blog/how-to-add-dynamic-meta-tags-server-side-with-create-react-app/ but how can I do it with a Django back-end? The files are also stored on AWS S3.